# Javascript knockout click binding

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, knockout.js

I have a javascript knockout button that i would like to disable for 3 second after the first click.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: editFile">
    Edit
</button>
```

I have tried

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: editFile, disable:disableButton">
    Edit
</button>
```

Then on JavaScript I did this. That disables the button completely.

```
disableButton = ko.observable("true");
```

I also tried pure JavaScript but that didn't work at all:

```
$(function() {
    $(".btn-default").click(function() {
        $(".btn-default").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        setTimeout(function() {
            $(".btn-default").removeAttr("disabled");      
        }, 3000);
    });
});
```

I tried following the example that was given by knockout but I don't think I'm doing it properly:

[Knockout example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/clickCounter.html)

Can someone please help I'm new to knockout and JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Refer below code snippet -

```js
function AppViewModel() {
    var _self = this;
    _self.disableButton = ko.observable(false);
    _self.editFile = function(){
     _self.disableButton(true);
        setTimeout(function() {
            _self.disableButton(false);
        }, 3000);
    };
}

// Activates knockout.js
ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.1.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-bind="click: editFile, disable:disableButton">
    Edit
</button>
```

You just need to update the observable true or false to enable/disable the Edit button.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried that before and that didn't work. I got a message saying: "Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."

Comment: Run the above code snippet, its working for me. If you are still getting the error for the this code then do share the error message!

Comment: I know it works on code snippet but I am getting an error saying "Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element."

Comment: I got it work by changing couple of things on the code.

Comment: by adding `self.disableEditButton = ko.observable(false)` to view model and then by adding this code under the editFile function: `self.disableButton(true);
        setTimeout(function() {
            self.disableButton(false);
        }, 3000);  `